# Multiple DoABC tags for boilerplate reuse

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, shockwave, avm2

I'm working on a tool for compiling TypeScript to SWF. I didn't get on the transformer for example yet, but I wanted to reused a little bit of boilerplate code from another `abc`. What I'm doing is simply contributing ABCs from a SWC to the output SWF, but does that work?

```
// ...
public mergeSWF(file: Buffer | string) {
    let swf = SwfReader.readSync(file);
    let symbolClasses = swf.tags.filter(tag => tag.code == SwfTagCode.SYMBOL_CLASS);
    let reassignedCharTagIds = new Map<number, number>();
    for (let tag of swf.tags) {
        if (tag.code == SwfTagCode.DO_ABC) {
            this.swfTags.push(tag);
        } else if (tag.code == SwfTagCode.DEFINE_BINARY_DATA) {
            // re-assign the character tag ID if already used.
            let binaryData = new SwfReader(ByteArray.from(tag.data!)).defineBinaryData();
            let prevTag = binaryData.tag;
            binaryData.tag = this.swfAlreadyUsedCharTagIds.has(binaryData.tag) ? this.nextSWFCharTagId() : binaryData.tag;
            this.swfAlreadyUsedCharTagIds.add(binaryData.tag);
            reassignedCharTagIds.set(prevTag, binaryData.tag);
            let newData = new SwfWriter();
            newData.ui16(binaryData.tag);
            newData.ui32(0);
            newData.binary(binaryData.data);
            tag.data = newData.toNodejsBuffer();
        }
    }
    for (let symbolClass of symbolClasses) {
        // re-assign the character tag IDs
        for (let symbol of symbolClass.symbols!) {
            symbol.id = reassignedCharTagIds.get(symbol.id)!;
        }

        this.swfTags.push(symbolClass);
    }
}
```

Can a `DoABC` in a SWF refer to another `DoABC` in the same SWF without merging the bytecodes (e.g. constant pool)?

Example:

- `lib.abc`

  - `q.b::C`
- `app.abc`

  - `Main` refers to `q.b::C` from `lib.abc`

Is this expected to work on the AVM2, given that `lib.abc` appears before `app.abc`?